# How do I force scrollbars on a Frame control created programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

Pretty simple question, for the life of me cannot figure out why `Frame` when created programmatically has no inherited `ScrollViewer` and thus no `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` or `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` properties.

How do I add scrollbars to this Frame (without just adding scrollbars to the frame source).

Note that I also have the Navigation UI visible and want to maintain the behavior of the fixed UI at the top with contents below that scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `Frame` inside a `ScrollBarViewer`..

Or simply set it via the attached properties `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and/or `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` in `ScrollViewer`

```
        Frame f = new Frame();
        ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(f, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
        ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(f, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but in the parent child relationship would not the frames navigation bar scroll with the page as well?

Comment: The `NavigationUI` does in fact scroll when the frame is the child of a `ScrollBarViewer`. If I did not wish to keep the nav ui this would be a viable solution.

Comment: Ahh, so its kind of like setting z order, you gotta reach out to another class to do it. Weird. `Frame` should just inherit `ScrollViewer`

Comment: It's just the concept of [Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Its just weird to wrap my head around trying to remember these external classes when trying to develop in an object oriented environment. Almost worth just writing an extension method to include in my project to handle this from now on.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by changing the `ContentTemplate` used by your `Frame` object so that its content is rendered with a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Frame>
    <Frame.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Frame.ContentTemplate>
</Frame>
```

Comment: To the down voter, could you give your reason for doing so? The above solution also solves the OP's original question, which was how to add scrollbars to their Frame's content that 1) didn't require them to add it to the Frame's source and 2) prevented the navigation UI from scrolling with the Frame's content.

Comment: Its an XAML solution thus no bearing on a programmatically created Frame as frames created at design time inherit the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility VerticalScrollBarVisibility properties automatically anyway thus no need for templates at all.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Thanks for the explanation!